# Getting an array of mysql data using data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

user table

- (userID)
- (username)
- (password)
- (email)
  etc...

Posts table

- (authorID)
- (postdata)

connections table

- (userID)
- (friendID)

I want to get only the posts data using the subscription.friendID as the posts.authorID, if the subscriptions.userID is the user.userID.

It's kinda confusing to me, hopefully someone can help me out. This is what i have so far, but i'm getting the subscription data aswell. I only want post table data.

```
 mysql_query("SELECT posts.*, connections.userID, connections.subID FROM posts, connections
        WHERE posts.userID = '$userid' AND posts.userID = connections.subID");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the post data, then do this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT posts.* FROM posts, connections
        WHERE posts.userID = '$userid' AND posts.userID = connections.subID");
```

As a superfluous note, if it is at all possible that $userid is being supplied by a user (through an HTML form, for example), be certain to at least run it through mysql_real_escape_string() before putting it in a query.  Otherwise you will be vulnerable to a SQL injection attack.  Even better would be to use a prepared statement via PDO or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a connections table in your original post so I'm going to work based on the schema you gave.

Based on what you wrote here I *think* you're looking for something like 'get all posts from some user's friends' - which would be:

```
     SELECT p.authorID, p.postdata
       FROM posts p
 INNER JOIN subscriptions s ON s.friendID = p.authorID    
      WHERE s.userID = '$userid'
```

This functionality would be akin to the wall feature on Facebook.

If you need more user info like username, you can join onto the user table as well.